# How to check if redux actionReducer axios request is successful or not

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm creating a page login with OTP, so first I sent request for login. If it's successful then my model would open for entering the otp.
But in my case model will open always because im unable to figure out how check if my request is successfult or not

I can manage state but I don't want to manage state for this simple task. I just want that the request in action reducer is successful or not. This will surely solves my problem easily.

```
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    let email= data.get('email');
    let password= data.get('password');

    await props.otpRequest(email,password);
    handleOTPModelOpen();
  };
```

Action Reducer

```
export const otpRequest = (email,password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_BACKEND
    dispatch(getOTPRequest())
    axios
      .post(`${url}/api/get_otp`,{
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getOTPSuccess())
        dispatch(showAlert(handleAxiosError(response),"success"));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(showAlert(handleAxiosError(error),"error"));
        dispatch(getOTPFailure())
        throw OTPRequestFailed()
      })
  }
}
```

and using mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchToken: (email,otp) => dispatch(fetchToken(email,otp)),
    otpRequest: (email,password) => dispatch(otpRequest(email,password))
  }
}
```

I just want to check if otpRequest is successful or not. Like that we checkedd in axios request in action reducer.

All request are successful no error is coming

Answer (score 0):

One nice way of handling this for most libraries is a `try / catch` block.

You could do this:

```
try { 
  await props.otpRequest(email,password);
  handleOTPModelOpen();
} catch (e) {
  // handle error here
  console.log(e);
  handleOTPFailed();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I don't see a selector or use of `mapStateToProps` callback. You use `mapDispatchToProps` which is great for the actions, however, in order to access the resulting `state`, you must also add `mapStateToProps`. Here's an example from one of my apps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    success: state.data.success;
  }
}
```

Think of `state` as a whole pie. A Redux `selector` allows you to take a `slice` of that pie and return it to the React component props for use, instead of the entire state (response from the API dispatch).

Comment: enen I raise a exception @wesley-lemahieu

Comment: Are you trying to access a value in the reducer? I don't know what your code looks like - there is not enough information. If you want to access a value in a `Reducer`, you must create a `Selector` for that value, then tie the `Selector` to your component. Are you using `mapStateToProps` with `React`? Update your question with much more context and I can help, thanks!

Comment: I have add more information please check if you found them useful to answer the problem